# Is it possible to connect SharePoint to an Access database without having information stored in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, database

It would ideally work like this. A user fills out a form in sharepoint and the information captured from the fields would be stored in a Microsoft access database and not in a sharepoint list. The reason no information can be stored in a list on share point is that it would contain sensitive information (SSN). Is something like this possible, is there any additional information anyone can point me to regarding this topic?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

you can check provider hosted add-in technology for this requirement. Using provider hosted add-in you can create custom applications which would use this database to store information. You can embed the add-in using add-in parts in your SharePoint page.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I will have to take this route.